# Footnote text ordered list

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, footnotes

I'm using XSL-FO and I have a problem with ordered list in footnote text.

In footnote text, the ordered list up to 99 is coming perfect and after there alignment is missing like `99,100,101`.

```
99   data here.
10
0    data here.
10
1    data here.
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: You have to increase the width reserved for the number in the ordered list; to get a more precise answer, you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44405981/edit) to include at least what output language you are using. A good question is one that contains a [_Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello ! i am using xslfo for output language. I can't find how to increase its width. Any default properties to increase width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you are looking for is [`provisional-distance-between-starts`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#provisional-distance-between-starts); it must be set on the `fo:list-block` element, for example:

```
<fo:list-block provisional-distance-between-starts="36pt">
    <fo:list-item>
        <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
            <fo:block>9999</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-label>
        <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
            <fo:block>Lorem ipsum</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-body>
    </fo:list-item>
</fo:list-block>
```

The fact that the list is inside a footnote is not relevant.

The point is that when `provisional-distance-between-starts` is not explicitly set **its default value is 24 points** which, as you experienced, may be less than the width of the labels.

According to the other formatting properties of your FO file and the formatter you are using, an insufficient label width leads to its text either being **wrapped** (as in your situation) or **overlapping** the list item body text.

Comment: Thank u very much for your explanation and it worked.